# Update Value in SQLlite Database Column Row

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I am currently learning android and I am confused at update specific column. I want +1 or -1 from that specific row in column. Example if there value is 15 and when I want add some value it must +1 = 16 in database. I have function for replace value 1 to 0 and 0 to 1 like below

```
  public void addOrRemoveFavorites(String id, String value) {
            ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
            values.put(QU_FAVORITE, value);
            database.update(TABLE_QUOTES, values, QU_ID + "=?", new String[] { id });
 }
```

My Update Query is like below

```
DAO.getInstance(getApplicationContext()).addOrRemoveFavorites(getQuote(mItemIndx).get(KEY_ID), !isChecked ? "1" : "0");
```

Anyone can please suggest me how I can I update value instead of replace it ?

Thanks

Comment: Show us insert query also

Comment: specify your question clearly. In first line you are saying update specific column but in second line you are saying  specific row in column. please clerify your  query in question.

Comment: please check my answer.

Comment: @Nisarg please check my updated question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you give an,  Example if there value is 15 and when I want add some value it must +1 = 16 in database, It is infering that you want to read previous data and then you want to increase it. if it is then there are two ways:

1. Create an trigger.
2. If you are not able to write an trigger then read the previous column data, then increase its value, then add it into the database. like:
   From your code:

   ```
    public void addOrRemoveFavorites(String id, String value) {
            ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
            values.put(QU_FAVORITE, value);
            database.update(TABLE_QUOTES, values, QU_ID + "=?", new String[] { id });
    }
   ```

If `value`  is the previous data then you can do one this here is that:

```
   public void addOrRemoveFavorites(String id, String value) {
               ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
               values.put(QU_FAVORITE, value+1);
               database.update(TABLE_QUOTES, values, QU_ID + "=?", new String[] { id });
         }
```

because reason is that, query `database.update(TABLE_QUOTES, values, QU_ID + "=?", new String[] { id });`  just replace the previous data.

Comment: This is fine and working as expected...Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 0):

**Try this**

```
 database.update(TABLE_QUOTES, values, QU_ID + " = ?",
            new String[] { String.valueOf(id) });
```

Comment: this is void function not else.

Comment: This does not changing anything....its same...replacing my value with value provided....I want increase value of row....